# How does Blazor know at runtime the environment?

Tags: blazor-webassembly

In Blazor WASM, I noticed that `webAssemblyHostBuilder.HostEnvironment.Environment` will output "Development" if it is on dev machine's browser and "Production" if it is on a deployed environment.

How does Blazor WASM know the environment given that it is disconnected from the server and loading in the browser? In other words, I expect the components running on the server to know the hosting environment because it is an environment variable, but how does Blazor 'extract' this information from the hosting environment?